# How can I consider an unfinished clock in clock table

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

I want to use org clocks to clock my time at work, I finish after 7:30 of clocked time every day.

I want to know what would be my total clocked time if I stopped the time right now, but the last clock is ignored in the `org-clock-table`.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the currently running clock in the report by altering variable `org-clock-report-include-clocking-task`.

Its documentation reads: "When non-nil, include the current clocking task time in clock reports."

So you could use

```
(setq org-clock-report-include-clocking-task t)
```

Or use `M-x customize-option org-clock-report-include-clocking-task` to set your preference.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please expand on your answer to make it more self-explanatory.  Future readers who find this post will appreciate it if you can give more explanation and context.

Comment: Hmm, I also came across this variable, but it does not seem to work for me. I have a clock running, but producing the report does not include that clock. Has this worked for anyone?